# What is Custom Block and Custom Block 2 for on the Product page?

Tags: product, custom-block

```
Magento 2.4.2
Smartwave Porto theme
```

I see the Short Description and Description is in the Content tab on the Product page (in Admin). **What exactly would we use the Custom Block and Custom Block 2 for?** *It seems odd/not logical to have these on the main page of the product while you actually have to click on CONTENT to see the Short Description and Description of the product which we need to use for every single product.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using this theme for one of our website. But we let these fields empty. My guess is that it's used for extra custom content that wouldn't suits description content...I think you can ignore them.